# xgboost - python model not same as c++ model

Tags: python, c++, xgboost

Consider the following python implementation of the xgboost fit function:

```
import xgboost as xgb
booster = xgb.XGBRegressor(
                base_score = 50, max_depth = 8, n_estimators=200,
                learning_rate=0.05, nthread=-1, subsample=1,
                colsample_bytree=1, min_child_weight = 1, scale_pos_weight = 1,
                seed=0, silent = False)
booster.fit(xValues, yValues, eval_metric="rmse")
```

I have to convert it to c++ (due to myriad reasons). I'm using the c_api to create the matrix and the learner functions to train:

```
XGDMatrixCreateFromMat(&xValues[0], rowCount, colCount, 0, &dMatrix);
XGDMatrixSetFloatInfo(dMatrix, "label", &yValues[0], rowCount);

learner = xgboost::Learner::Create(dMatrix);
learner->Configure(learnerConfig); //same config params as above
learner->InitModel();

for(int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
    learner->UpdateOneIter(i, xValues);

auto fo(dmlc::Stream::Create("save.model", "w"));
learner->Save(fo.get());
```

Technically, this should give similar models from Python and C++. However, the predictions I'm getting from the two models are very varied when I'm using the exact same prediction function for the two models.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I rewrote the C++ function to use the c_api throughout:

```
BoosterHandle h_booster;
XGBoosterCreate(dmats, 1, &h_booster);

for(auto cfg : m_learnerConfig)
  XGBoosterSetParam(h_booster, cfg.first.c_str(), cfg.second.c_str());

for(size_t iter = 0; iter < nNumTrees; ++iter)
  XGBoosterUpdateOneIter(h_booster, iter, matrices[0]);

XGBoosterSaveModel(h_booster, filename);
```

There is no change in the generated model. The C++ model tends to give higher predicted values than the python model. However, it is not consistent.

Just to confirm: To compare, I'm using the same prediction code/logic in C++, using the two saved model files.

Here's a sample of how it differs.
[image: xgboost prediction - C++ vs Python models]

Comment: did you manage to find the problem, I'm facing the same problem, but c++ it's giving lower values, with the same params, maybe in python some params default values redfined!